# Constructing a string in OpenSCAD

Tags: string, list, openscad

In OpenSCAD, I'd like to create a string, `pattern`, that starts with 'a', ends with 'c', and has enough 'b's in the middle that `len(pattern)` is equal to `units`.  For example, if `units` is 5, `pattern` should be "abbbc".

The best solution I have so far is a list comprehension:

```
pattern = [if (units > 0) "a",
           if (units > 2) for (i = [1:units - 2]) "b",
           if (units > 1) "c"];
```

This will do, but ideally I'd like to make a string from this list?  I tried `str(pattern)`, but that gives a string representation of the list, with brackets, quotes, and commas.

Is there an alternative to the list comprehension that naturally results in a string?

Comment: Not sure if that's the simplest way, but this would do the conversion: function to_str(v, i = 0, s = "") = i >= len(v)
           ? s
           : to_str(v, i + 1, str(s, v[i]));

Comment: @TorstenPaul:  I hope OpenSCAD is good at tail recursion!

Comment: I'm sure this function will hit the tail recursion elimination at least in the latest release version. It does currently cap those at 1 million iterations though. OpenSCAD is not super fast but it's dumping that in about 1 second on my system: echo(to_str([for (a = [0:100000]) chr(a % 26 + 97) ]));